# Binarize turning image completely black?

Tags: image-processing

Running Binarize (or EdgeDetect) on a filled black and white image is resulting in an all black image.

The image has the following color distribution (with most images points falling in either a zero or one bucket)

```
image = Import["http://imgur.com/HhsMeDc.png"] ;
ImageLevels[ image, 10 ]
...
{{{0., 640000}, {0.1, 0}, {0.2, 0}, {0.3, 0}, {0.4, 0}, {0.5,
   0}, {0.6, 0}, {0.7, 0}, {0.8, 0}, {0.9, 0}},
 {{0., 640000}, {0.1,
   0}, {0.2, 0}, {0.3, 0}, {0.4, 0}, {0.5, 0}, {0.6, 0}, {0.7,
   0}, {0.8, 0}, {0.9, 0}},
 {{0., 640000}, {0.1, 0}, {0.2, 0}, {0.3,
   0}, {0.4, 0}, {0.5, 0}, {0.6, 0}, {0.7, 0}, {0.8, 0}, {0.9,
   0}},
 {{0., 370003}, {0.1, 809}, {0.2, 605}, {0.3, 555}, {0.4,
   612}, {0.5, 550}, {0.6, 580}, {0.7, 616}, {0.8, 764}, {0.9,
   264906}}}
```

[image: dragon]

This binarize attempt:

```
b = Binarize[ image ] 
ImageLevels[ b ]
```

produces an all black image, with the levels showing only zero values:

```
 {{0, 640000}, {1, 0}}
```

I tried various thresholds, including the default and some explicit values (or 0.5, 0.9, 0.1, ...), but still get the all zero levels?

Comment: Not sure why, but `ColorNegate@Binarize[ColorNegate[image]]` seems to do the job.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The reason is that this `PNG` image is defined **purely** by applying an alpha channel to a completely uniform foreground color. The alpha channel however is ignored in `Binarize` and therefore you get a uniform output. You can see this by saying

```
RemoveAlphaChannel[image]
```

[image: black]

and

```
AlphaChannel[image]
```

[image: alppha]

The latter shows the shape, while the former doesn't contain any shape.